# Bluebird, Promise.bind - how to access bound context in pending promise?

Tags: promise, bluebird

Someone pointed me to `Promise.bind()` in bluebird to be able to have a context in a promise chain.

However, my use case requires me to use this context "from outside" when I only have reference to the promise object (the one with the `then` and `catch` API).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, `.bind` has a non-static counterpart.

```
yourPromise.bind({x:3}).then(function(data){
     console.log("yourPromise fulfilled with", data, "and x is ", this.x);
});
```

Here is a [fiddle illustrating the usage](http://jsfiddle.net/DpDbn/).

Comment: I meant accessing the context when the promise is still pending - before `then()` happens.

Comment: @Madd0g you want to access the already set context of a Bluebird promise? Well, I know for a fact that you _can_ do that - but I recommend you don't as it's an internal thing. Why not just monkey patch properties to the promise object itself? Or pass additional parameters?

Comment: Just to get a better understanding, does [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jEb36/) illustrate what you were looking to do? Can you elaborate on why?

Comment: Yes, that fiddle is exactly what I need - my problem is that I have a lot of places that use a function that returns a promise, I wanted to expose another property to these callers without refactoring all the callers

Comment: @Madd0g Does putting it on the promise work for you http://jsfiddle.net/LYJJ3/ :)?

Comment: I suppose that's what you meant by monkey patching. I don't actually mind that, but if I do `c.x = 3;` and then `return c.promise.error(errorHandler)` - is that still the same object that has the `x` property? It's hard to know without knowing the internals

Comment: @Madd0g no, it is not. Promises are immutable in the sense they return a new promise whenever you extend them (so c.error does _not_ mutate c, but rather create a _new_ promise with that property). There is a notion of _subclassing_ promises and _eventually_ it will be possible to do this (currently no one, including ES6 promises does this). If you think about it logically - since your users expect a promise, whatever you're returning _must_ subclass promise anyway - so your only real options are to monkey patch it, or change the return value. Personally, I'd change the return value.

Comment: Thanks, I played around with it and now I understand it a lot better. I really like `bind()` for promises. I ended up monkey patching, but learned important lessons along the way :)